# WIX installer remove disk cost message from CustomizeDlg

Tags: wix, wix3.7

Is there a way to remove Disk Cost messages from CustomizeDlg?. 
For some reason when there is a feature and a sub feature, the main feature shows very little "disk cost" and when clicking on the sub-feature it shows correct "disk cost".

I would like to simply remove that message.
thanks

Comment: Please, follow this link
[Override localization strings for Feature-costing in Wix](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Feature-costing-td1307593.html) This solution was helpful for me.